# Variable \"$data\" of required type "Type" was not provided

Tags: graphql, prisma-graphql, graphql-mutation, nexus-prisma, prisma2

I have a survey creation mutation and I want to create nested records with survey creation mutation. I am using query variables to set the data for mutation. When I create only survey without nested attributes it works successfully but when I add nested attributes I get the error as attached.
I have a backend in nexus prisma2.

Quick help will highly be appreciated.

[image]

[image]

Comment: input structure?

Comment: @xadm you can see input structure in the screenshot of playground that I have written inside query variables.

Comment: no, there is no `SurveyCreateInput` type definition - screenshot contains only name of this type, nothing about structure